# How to add close button in MFC dialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC dialog which displays an image.
I added this code

```
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

SetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX |WS_CLOSE);
```

but I still don't get a close button on title bar.
Please tell me how to get a close button.

Comment: Just curious: from what header did you get the WS_CLOSE symbol?

Comment: Actually I added that. I found the control for maximize and minimize buttons. But they don't work either.

Comment: "Added" ? What value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `WS_SYSMENU` style instead of `WS_CLOSE`

Comment: Great.. it works. :)
But the maximize and minimize buttons still don't come

Comment: They should be here. Why don't you use the RC file for styles? Post your actual Ressource Template.